# how to get selected dropdown value in angular 5 using <p-dropdown> (primeng) facing issues because of ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng

Actually my values are getting populated in ngOnInit() so event is not available there I need to get previous selected value even after refreshing page.

```
 <p-dropdown [options]="Options" [(ngModel)]="Id" (onChange)="onChange($event)" ></p-dropdown>
```

OnChange its populating data for another dropdown and previous value is available within event. But my options are getting populated from ngOnInit() so as the page getting refreshed it takes all options value from ngOnint.

I have tried this but this.currentValue is undefined when I use in another method.strong text

this.currentValue = event.value

I am not familiar much with angular. Anybody can help ?

Thanks,

Comment: Bad tagging. Please check if you actually use all tags that you used on the question.

Comment: Did you get the answer?if you get please share here...

Comment: @akhil, I resolved it by putting that value in sessionStorage from event because everytime ngOninit intitialize all values and we get value blank. so from onChange(event) you can get value and put in session for using it again.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
(onChange)="onChange($event)"
```

To:

```
(change)="onChange(Id)"
```

And Check in typescript function like:

```
onChange(event){ console.log(event) }
```